# Phonegap on Samsung S4 Errors - Canvas not working well

Tags: android, cordova, galaxy

My app is working well on other phones without errors.

I recently tested my app on an actual Samsung S4 and all of my canvas drawings are messed up. Some times they draw and sometimes they don't, it seems completely random. No errors are thrown regarding the canvas draw commands. I am not using any transitions.

After reading many posts I disabled hardware acceleration by using

```
super.appView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

And I also used the following to ensure the viewport wouldn't be skewed due to the higher resolution

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

Now when I run the app I do see some strange errors that are not seen when testing on other phones. I searched the net but didn't learn too much about them.

```
E/SELinux(23616): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
E/ViewRootImpl(23616): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
E/SpannableStringBuilder(23616): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(23616): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

I have no idea what these errors mean. sendUserActionEvent? I am not sending any action events. SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE? I do not have any spans...

Are there any other tips on getting Phonegap to run well on the S4???

Here is my full log

```
10-29 19:11:22.189:

E/SELinux(23616): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts

10-29 19:11:22.189: D/dalvikvm(23616): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-29 19:11:22.279: D/CordovaActivity(23616): Setting integer properties in CordovaActivity will be deprecated in 3.0 on July 2013, please use config.xml
10-29 19:11:22.289: I/CordovaLog(23616): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-29 19:11:22.289: D/CordovaActivity(23616): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
10-29 19:11:22.289: D/CordovaActivity(23616): Setting integer properties in CordovaActivity will be deprecated in 3.0 on July 2013, please use config.xml
10-29 19:11:22.349: I/webclipboard(23616): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@422752e8
10-29 19:11:22.379: D/CordovaWebView(23616): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: samsung
10-29 19:11:22.389: D/JsMessageQueue(23616): Set native->JS mode to 2
10-29 19:11:22.389: D/CordovaActivity(23616): CordovaActivity.init()
10-29 19:11:22.409: V/webkit(23616): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {4226f018}
10-29 19:11:22.459: D/dalvikvm(23616): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 8% free 18099K/19532K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
10-29 19:11:22.459: I/dalvikvm-heap(23616): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.387MB for 2764816-byte allocation
10-29 19:11:22.479: D/dalvikvm(23616): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 7% free 20796K/22236K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
10-29 19:11:22.489: D/dalvikvm(23616): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 7% free 20807K/22236K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 17ms
10-29 19:11:22.499: D/CordovaWebView(23616): loadUrlIntoView(file:///android_asset/www/splash.html, 10000)
10-29 19:11:22.499: D/CordovaActivity(23616): onMessage(splashscreen,show)
10-29 19:11:22.499: D/CordovaWebView(23616): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-29 19:11:22.499: D/PluginManager(23616): init()
10-29 19:11:22.509: D/CordovaWebView(23616): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-29 19:11:22.509: D/WebView(23616): loadUrlImpl: called
10-29 19:11:22.509: D/webcore(23616):  CORE loadUrl: called
10-29 19:11:22.509: D/webkit(23616): Firewall not null
10-29 19:11:22.509: D/webkit(23616): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
10-29 19:11:22.509: I/CordovaLog(23616): Found start page location: splash.html
10-29 19:11:22.509: I/CordovaLog(23616): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-29 19:11:22.509: D/CordovaActivity(23616): Resuming the App
10-29 19:11:22.509: D/CordovaActivity(23616): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
10-29 19:11:22.549: D/libEGL(23616): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
10-29 19:11:22.549: D/libEGL(23616): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
10-29 19:11:22.549: D/libEGL(23616): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
10-29 19:11:22.549: I/Adreno200-EGL(23616): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
10-29 19:11:22.549: I/Adreno200-EGL(23616): Build Date: 04/22/13 Mon
10-29 19:11:22.549: I/Adreno200-EGL(23616): Local Branch: adreno_sba_20130419
10-29 19:11:22.549: I/Adreno200-EGL(23616): Remote Branch:
10-29 19:11:22.549: I/Adreno200-EGL(23616): Local Patches:
10-29 19:11:22.549: I/Adreno200-EGL(23616): Reconstruct Branch:
10-29 19:11:22.619: D/OpenGLRenderer(23616): Enabling debug mode 0
10-29 19:11:22.619: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(23616): Ignore this event
10-29 19:11:22.629: D/WebView(23616): onSizeChanged - w:1080 h:1920
10-29 19:11:22.629: D/CordovaActivity(23616): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-29 19:11:22.760: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(23616): Ignore this event
10-29 19:11:22.770: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(23616): Ignore this event
10-29 19:11:23.400: I/Web Console(23616): BUILD TITLE: height: 480 width: 1080:135
10-29 19:11:23.410: D/skia(23616): new locale
10-29 19:11:23.420: I/GATE(23616): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
10-29 19:11:23.420: D/CordovaWebViewClient(23616): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-29 19:11:23.420: D/CordovaActivity(23616): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/splash.html)
10-29 19:11:23.470: D/CordovaActivity(23616): onMessage(spinner,stop)
10-29 19:11:23.470: D/CordovaNetworkManager(23616): Connection Type: wifi
10-29 19:11:23.480: D/TilesManager(23616): Starting TG #0, 0x6d237b38
10-29 19:11:23.480: D/TilesManager(23616): new EGLContext from framework: 40fc0920
10-29 19:11:23.480: D/GLWebViewState(23616): Reinit shader
10-29 19:11:23.490: D/CordovaActivity(23616): onMessage(splashscreen,hide)
10-29 19:11:23.490: I/App(23616): WARNING: Back Button Default Behaviour will be overridden.  The backbutton event will be fired!
10-29 19:11:23.680: D/GLWebViewState(23616): Reinit transferQueue
10-29 19:11:23.721: D/CordovaNetworkManager(23616): Connection Type: wifi
10-29 19:11:23.721: D/CordovaActivity(23616): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
10-29 19:11:23.821:

E/ViewRootImpl(23616): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

E/SpannableStringBuilder(23616): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

E/SpannableStringBuilder(23616): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

10-29 19:11:25.432: D/CordovaActivity(23616): onMessage(spinner,stop)
10-29 19:12:00.266: D/CordovaActivity(23616): Paused the application!
10-29 19:12:00.266: D/CordovaWebView(23616): Handle the pause
10-29 19:12:00.266: D/WebView(23616): loadUrlImpl: called
10-29 19:12:00.266: D/webcore(23616):  CORE loadUrl: called
10-29 19:12:00.266: D/webkit(23616): Firewall not null
10-29 19:12:00.266: D/webkit(23616): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
10-29 19:12:00.837: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23616): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue in cordova. Did you find any answer for that?